# Is Mongodb can be used with magento

Tags: magento2

Is it possible to move the caching system of magento to mongo db ,

If the product entity moved to magento then

It would be easy to have fastest website

as search and people will get faster

Comment: how exactly this get faster? what caching system you referring to?

Comment: Are talking about cache or moving Product entity to  mongo?